Use macro to dynamically insert static formula reference to an Excel sheet
I am trying to create a maintenance log for various pieces of equipment, where there is a sheet with a detailed log for each piece, and an overview sheet with some basic info. I have a macro set up to create a new sheet and enter the necessary data from a userform.
I am also trying to get this macro to insert a new row on the overview sheet with references to this new equipment sheet on the overview with a formula like ='sheetname'!cell. The problem is the formula is being placed in the cell using a variable, so every time I add a new sheet, every instance of the formula updates to reference the newest sheet. How can I input my sheet name variable as just text, or otherwise break the link between the formula and variable?
For reference, here is the code I am using to try and create the reference.
Edit: I have added all of the code for what I am trying to do. Since I have been messing with it more, I have realized that not only the variables are updating in the cell references, but the entire formula is updating. So, both the sheet name and cell reference are changing with each use of the macro.
Sub SubmitBttn_Click()

'Define Variables
    model = modeltxtbx.Value
    ser = serialtxtbx.Value
    loc = loctxtbx.Value
    frq = frqtxtbx.Value
    oil = OilBox.Value
    
    
    
    Call CheckExisting(model, ser, loc, frq, oil)
    
End Sub

Sub CheckExisting(model, ser, loc, frq, oil)
'Check For Entry
    If model = "" Then
        
        'err = MsgBox("Please Enter Pump Model", vbCritical)
       ' If Response = vbOK Then
           ' modeltxtbx.SetFocus
            
        
    End If

'Check For existing sheet
    For i = 2 To Worksheets.count - 1
        If InStr(1, Worksheets(i).Name, model) > 0 Then
            If Worksheets(i).Range("E1").Value = ser Then
                Worksheets(i).Activate
                Beep
                dup = True
                err = MsgBox("This Pump Model and Serial No. Already Exist. Return to Form?", vbYesNo)
                
                Select Case err
                Case Is = vbYes
                    serialtxtbx.SetFocus
                Case Is = vbNo
                    Unload AddPumpLog
                    Exit Sub
                End Select
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    
    
    Select Case dup
        Case Is = True
            Unload Me
        Case Is = False
            Call AddPump(model, ser, loc, frq, oil)
            Unload Me
    End Select
End Sub
    
Public Sub AddPump(model, ser, loc, frq, oil)
'Add new sheet
    Sheets("Template").Select
    Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.count)
    
'Move Template to End
    Worksheets("Template").Move After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.count)
    Worksheets("Overview").Activate
'Rename Sheet

    'Count Duplicate Names
    x = 0
    For i = 2 To Worksheets.count - 1
        If InStr(1, Worksheets(i).Name, model) > 0 Then
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next i
    'Name based on
    'If x = 0 Then
        'nom = model
    'End If
        
    'If Not x = 0 Then
       nom = model & "(" & x + 1 & ")"
   ' End If
            
    'Rename Sheet
    Sheets("Template (2)").Name = nom
        
    'Populate data
    Sheets(nom).Range("B1").Value = loc
    Sheets(nom).Range("D1").Value = nom
    Sheets(nom).Range("E1").Value = ser
    Sheets(nom).Range("F1").Value = frq
    Sheets(nom).Range("C1").Value = oil
    
'Add To Overview
    'Add Row to Overview
    Worksheets("Overview").ListObjects("OverviewTable").ListRows.Add
    r = Sheets("Overview").Cells(Sheet1.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    

    
    
    'Add Linked Values
    Sheets("Overview").Cells(r, 1).Value = "='" & nom & "'!$D$1"
    Sheets("Overview").Cells(r, 2).Value = "='" & nom & "'!$E$1"
    Sheets("Overview").Cells(r, 3).Formula = "='" & nom & "'!$C$4"
    Sheets("Overview").Cells(r, 4).Value = "='" & nom & "'!$E$4"
    Sheets("Overview").Cells(r, 5).Value = "='" & nom & "'!$A$"
    Sheets("Overview").Cells(r, 6).Value = "='" & nom & "'!$B$"
    Sheets("Overview").Cells(r, 7).Value = "='" & nom & "'!$D$"

    


     
    
    Set t = ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 8)
    Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
        btn.OnAction = "LogEntry"
    With btn
        .Characters.Text = "Add Log Entry"
        .Name = "AddEntry"
    End With
    
    
    'Add Show Log Button
    Set t = ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 9)
    Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
    With btn
      .OnAction = "ShowLog"
      .Caption = "ShowLog"
      .Name = "Showlg"
      
    End With
    
     
    Unload Me
End Sub



You never assign nom a value. Can you explain "defined by the userform input"?

Maybe add the rest of your code?

nom = modeltxtbx.value
Where modeltxtbx is the name of the userform textbox.
I haven't posted the rest of the code, because this variable is the only part that is not working correctly. This code inputs the reference, but every time I rerun the code, the references update, so all of my references go to the same sheet instead of various different sheets.

Excel formula will not be updated of the new sheet name. This happens because you select the last row in your table, and your code overwrite it when create the new sheet.

You can set the formula through the `Formula' property:
Dim nom as String
Sheets("Overview").Cells(r, 2).Formula = "='" & nom & "'!$E$1"


The problem you further met is related to Excel tables (aka ListObjects in VBA). If you enter a formula into the table, the formula applies to the whole column.
Below I explain how to remove the table from the sheet but consider the recommendation that you don't need to use formulas in the Overview table since these data are constant (almost?).
To remove the table object and work with data as with the normal range:

In "Overview" sheet, in "Name Box", select "OverviewTable".
Right-click on the selected cells and command "Table-->Convert to Range" then confirm.
Apply the autofitler.
In the code, comment the line which refers ListObject and increment r by 1:

    ' Worksheets("Overview").ListObjects("OverviewTable").ListRows.Add
    r = Sheets("Overview").Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

So, there are two solutions for your choice for the Overview table:

Use constants.
Convert the table to the range.


I have tried using that property as well. The problem is this inserts the sheet name as a variable. So, when I make a sheet for equipment name ABC, the references are input as
"=ABC!cell"
But then when I add a sheet for equipment name DEF, both references become
"=DEF!cell"
Near as I can tell, this is because the "nom" variable is staying as a variable in the formula, so everytime I rerun the macro, "nom" is redefined, and all instances in the formulas get updated to the newest value.

It's up to you. You need to assign nom the appropriate value to set the correct formula.

the value of "nom" is set by the code each time the macro runs. The idea is the user clicks a button, which calls a user form. They enter the required data into the form, and then the form creates a new sheet for that piece of equipment, and the overview sheet shows values referenced on that new sheet. It appears that these formulas are being rewritten every time the macro runs, so instead of each row referencing a different sheet, they all go to the same sheet. Is there a way to make the formula unchangeable after it has been inserted in the cell?

Pls. provide your complete code for "the form creates a new sheet for that piece of equipment, and the overview sheet shows values referenced on that new sheet".

Converting to range solved the problem. Thank you for the help.
